# what does this sentence mean？

Tags: reading-comprehension

> しかし、そういった考えは許されないようだ。なぜか個性とは、常識的な考えからいって褒められるものでなければいけないのである。そうなると、**今言われている個性とは、一般的にいいとされる個性というものがすでにいくつかあって、それをどう獲得するかを考えなければならないということになる**。しかし、そんなものは個性ではないし、結局は人と同じになってしまうのである。

this sentence literally mean "nowadays,when we talk about 個性、there are already some good 個性、how to obtain them is remain to think",but I don't know what the author want to convey under the context

Comment: What exactly is your doubt?

Answer (score 1):

"For some reason, our society decided that uniqueness should be something to be celebrated. If so, the "uniqueness" that we talk of today must be something like the following: there is a pre-existing selection of "uniquenesses", and people are expected to figure out how to acquire these pre-determined "uniquenesses". But then, that isn't a "uniqueness" at all and would lead to people being similar to each other after all."

Comment: thank you,you answer helps